# Separation of string

Tags: objective-c, ios, string, nsstring

I have a string of 4 words, how do I separate it into 2 strings each consisting of two words?
The code:

```
 NSString * myString= @"AAAA bbbbb CCCC ddddd";
```

I want to separate this string into 2 strings:

```
NSString *firstString =@"AAAA bbbbb";
NSString *secondString =@"CCCC ddddd";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSArray's `componentsSeperatedByString` to break the string up into parts. From there you can use some simple string formatting to piece the new strings together from the contents of the array.

```
NSString *inputString= @"AAAA bbbbb CCCC ddddd";
NSArray *array = [inptString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSString *outputStringOne = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [array objectAtIndex:0], [array objectAtIndex:1]];
NSString *outputStringTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [array objectAtIndex:2], [array objectAtIndex:3]];
```